# What happened to bootstrap options in PHPUnit 3.6?

Tags: php, phpunit, bootstrapping

The `bootstrap` configuration options is commented out in the latest version of the `phpunit.xml` documentation:
http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html

And indeed, it doesn't seem to be reading it in my configuration file. Why is this? How do I configure phpunit 3.6 to automatically include a bootstrap file?

It seems to me like it is extremely useful to setup your project so PHPUnit would automatically provisioned with a bootstrap file without the person running PHPUnit having to be aware of it, so they could simply do:

```
> phpunit
```

rather than:

```
> phpunit --bootstrap [file]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the configuration file for PHPUnit, in version `3.4` you could include a bootstrap file as follows:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="true"
         bootstrap="/path/to/bootstrap.php"
```

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/appendixes.configuration.html

But as of `3.5` this options has been commented out, so you can no longer use it:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="true"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         <!--bootstrap="/path/to/bootstrap.php"-->
```

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/appendixes.configuration.html

I can't find any reference as to why this option has been disabled. I looked for release notes for PHPUnit `3.5` to see if they mentioned anything, but nothing I found mentioned bootstrap at all.

http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/897-PHPUnit-3.5.html

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.5/README.markdown

I would still welcome a comment from anyone who knows why this options has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

the bootstrap file should run before the tests and it is an available command line option for phpunit

`--bootstrap <file>`

more information on cli options:

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions

i've never used the xml config file for the bootstrap option, so i don't know why its not or no longer working, but hopefully cli works like it does for me :)

Comment: Ah. I know about the CLI option. I'm using it at the moment, but I'm doing an assignment and I want my assessor to be able to just run `phpunit` in the route of my project without any extra options.

Comment: have you tried other versions of phpunit? e.g. an older or newer unstable one? maybe its just broken in that special version. i don't have other ideas atm, sorry.